# Prevent Google One Tap to show on some pages

Tags: javascript, google-identity, google-one-tap

I am using both Google One Tap and Signin with Google button in my site. Google One Tap is showing on all pages and Signing with Google button is visible only on the login page.

I am initializing both with the Javascript API.

My question is how to hide the Google One Tap on the login page ?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely something you can do.

The JavaScript code for the GIS is:

```
// Initialise the GIS Authentication client
const client = google.accounts.id.initialize({
  client_id: YOUR_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID,
  callback: (response) => {
    registerOrLogin(parseJwt(response.credential))
  }
});

google.accounts.id.renderButton(
  document.getElementById("siwgButton"),
);
```

And the One Tap displayed when you call this function:

```
google.accounts.id.prompt();
```

You can condition this last line of code based on which page you are on. This will achieve what you describe I think?